# incrementing autoresetevent c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, autoresetevent

Is there an incrementing AutoResetEvent, or something similar in c# libraries?

How would one go about rolling an efficient implementation of one, or alternatively, address the problem stated without doing so?

**Problem:** To clarify my need, I have a producer / consumer situation, where I have an unknown number of producers, and a fixed number of consumers.

**Edit**:Forgot to mention one issue, I cannot use .NET 4.0 so I cannot use `ConcurrentQueue<T>` :'( , I need to stick with .NET 2.0 for now.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy12yx1f%28en-us,VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out if [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) would work for your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen .NET 4's [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx)? It takes care of all of that for you.

Since you can't use .NET 4, you can use [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) in the `System.Threading` namespace.

Comment: ah! I forgot to mention, I cannot use .NET 4.0, as I need .Net 2.0 conformance for the system! What would you suggest then?

Comment: A.White Thanks, but as I understood, this is not incrementing. i.e ' two calls are too close together, so that the second call occurs before a thread has been released, only one thread is released. It is as if the second call did not happen. ' - msdn documentation. So the servicing thread will only service one item from the queue, and not two as it should.

Comment: That is what happens when developers use an event instead of a semaphore.  There are hundreds of posts on here, and other groups, that suggest 'use an auto/manual event' whenever some developer wants a producer-consumer queue.  Nobody knows why.  It's like wasps - they do no good, cause lots of pain and no-one, (save maybe your God/intelligent designer), knows why they were developed.